# Generating grid with Array().fill() results in shared references between cells

Tags: javascript

I generate a 3x3 grid

```js
const grid = Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(0))
```

```js
[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0]]
```

I set the value of the middle cell to `1`

```js
grid[1][1] = 1
```

I expect to see

```js
[[0,0,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,0,0]]
```

but instead see

```js
[[0,1,0]
 [0,1,0],
 [0,1,0]]
```

It seems that all rows are referring to the same array in memory.
A `console.log(grid)` shows

```js
[[0, 1, 0],
 [circular object Array],
 [circular object Array]]
```

What exactly is going on? How can I properly generate a matrix where each cell is independent?

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Array.fill) before you post

Answer (score 0):

`Array(3).fill(0)` creates a new array. But it creates only one array. Now you are filling the outer `Array(3).fill` with the same array three times. The reference is same for all `grid[x]` where x lies from 0 to 2.

Here is the relevant [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#parameters).

If `value` is the value to be filled using `Array.fill(value)`:

> Note all elements in the array will be this exact value: if value is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object.

You are better off using a loop:

```js
const grid = [];

for(let i =0 ; i < 3; i++){
grid.push(Array(3).fill(0));
}
grid[1][1]=1;
console.log(grid);
```